# Re-declaring an identifier in ES6

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Most likely a stupid questions, but is there a way to re-declare a variable with the same identifier? For the sake of naming conventions I would like to do something similiar to the following.

```
export let Navbar = styled(Navbar)` STYLES GO HERE `
```

I however can't add styles to Navbar and keep the identifier as Navbar because of the scoping. Navbar is already declared.

Any thoughts? We are trying to wrap our components with styling but keep them named the same.

This for instance would work, but breaks the convention that we are using for regular html elements.

```
export let StyledNavbar = styled(Navbar)` STYLES GO HERE `
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for

```
Navbar = styled(Navbar)` STYLES GO HERE `
export {Navbar}
```

?

You can assign a new value to the variable (if it was declared with `let` or `var` and export it.

You could do that the other way round:

```
export let Navbar = initialValue;
Navbar = styled(Navbar)` STYLES GO HERE `
```

Comment: Thanks this was it. I didn't need "let" which makes a ton of sense as the component was imported.

Comment: Ok I lied. I had the static site built that was giving me a false positive. The problem still exists. Any component I import from another package I cannot redeclare even using let or var.

Comment: Yes, imports are readonly. You have to create a new variable then. No way around it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following should work:

```
const StyledNavbar = styled(Navbar);
export { StyledNavbar as Navbar };
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using composition?

```
const StyledNavbar = style.div`
    padding: 10px;
    background: blue;
    font-size: 12px;
`

export class Navbar extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <StyledNavbar>Hello World</StyledNavbar>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will be the best fit for your use case but you can use aliases

```
import {NavBar as StyledNav} from "./navBar;
const NavBar = styled(StyledNav)`YOUR CODE HERE`;
```